# React-Native OneSignal Android error: OneSignal.init has not been called

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I'm trying to use the OneSignal react native package to send push notifications to my users. This is working fine for iOS. However, on Android, every call to the `OneSignal` library times out. When I run `adb logcat` I see the following message in my console:

> E/OneSignal: OneSignal.init has not been called. Could not get OSPermissionSubscriptionState

According to the documentation (https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/docs/react-native-sdk-setup), this is not a step I should do manually, but is rather performed by the library itself when setting up the subscription. I have written some helper functions for OneSignal that are throwing the error above:

```
getPermissionSubscriptionState = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState((state) =>{
            console.log(state);
            resolve(state);
        });
    });
}

enablePushnotifications = async () => {
    OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
}

ensureSubscription = async () =>  {
    const status = await this.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
    console.log(status);
    if(!status.notificationsEnabled && !status.hasPrompted) {
        this.enablePushnotifications();
    }
    return status;
}
```

In my root component, I invoke the `ensureSubscription` method like so: `await OneSignalHelper.ensureSubscription();`. Inside `ensureSubscription()` I invoke the `getPermissionSubscriptionState()`, but as soon as I do that the above error is printed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but couldn't the solution be to ask for some permission on androidManifest?

Comment: I've got the permissions they tell you to add in the documentation in my manifest sadly.

Comment: Just to be sure, they say add one of those, is that what you did?